# Move an array element to a new index in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking for a simple function to move an array element to a new position in the array and resequence the indexes so that there are no gaps in the sequence. It doesnt need to work with associative arrays. Anyone got ideas for this one?

```
$a = array(
      0 => 'a',
      1 => 'c',
      2 => 'd',
      3 => 'b',
      4 => 'e',
);
print_r(moveElement(3,1))
//should output 
    [ 0 => 'a',
      1 => 'b',
      2 => 'c',
      3 => 'd',
      4 => 'e' ]
```

Comment: Some code with expected result would help ...

Answer (score 127, accepted):

As commented, 2x `array_splice`, there even is no need to renumber:

```
$array = [
    0 => 'a', 
    1 => 'c', 
    2 => 'd', 
    3 => 'b', 
    4 => 'e',
];

function moveElement(&$array, $a, $b) {
    $out = array_splice($array, $a, 1);
    array_splice($array, $b, 0, $out);
}

moveElement($array, 3, 1);
```

> *redzarf* comments: *"To clarify `$a` is `$fromIndex` and `$b` is `$toIndex`"*

Result:

```
[
    0 => 'a',
    1 => 'b',
    2 => 'c',
    3 => 'd',
    4 => 'e',
];
```

Comment: Yes it is nice and simple solution, but it works only if old index is greater than new index. Here is another solution: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212312/moving-up-down-an-item-in-the-array-by-its-value)

Comment: @quarky: No, it works as well if new index is greater than old index. As well if both are the same.

Comment: But if your destination is AFTER the source, it may not place it where you predict, because the array gets shorter after the first step. If moving to the end, you don't want to use size-1, you want size-2

Comment: @GarrGodfrey: Honestly, I've never seen code that works well with predictions. But thanks for your feedback.

Comment: It seems that if the offset is greater than the array size, array_splice uses the array size instead, so this works.

Comment: To clarify `$a` is `$fromIndex` and `$b` is `$toIndex`

Answer (score 13):

A lot of good answers. Here's a simple one built on the answer by @RubbelDeCatc. The beauty of it is that you only need to know the array key, not its current position (before repositioning).

```
/**
 * Reposition an array element by its key.
 *
 * @param array      $array The array being reordered.
 * @param string|int $key They key of the element you want to reposition.
 * @param int        $order The position in the array you want to move the element to. (0 is first)
 *
 * @throws \Exception
 */
function repositionArrayElement(array &$array, $key, int $order): void
{
    if(($a = array_search($key, array_keys($array))) === false){
        throw new \Exception("The {$key} cannot be found in the given array.");
    }
    $p1 = array_splice($array, $a, 1);
    $p2 = array_splice($array, 0, $order);
    $array = array_merge($p2, $p1, $array);
}
```

Straight forward to use:

```
$fruits = [
    'bananas'=>'12', 
    'apples'=>'23',
    'tomatoes'=>'21', 
    'nuts'=>'22',
    'foo'=>'a',
    'bar'=>'b'
];

repositionArrayElement($fruits, "foo", 1);

var_export($fruits);

/** Returns
array (
  'bananas' => '12',
  'foo' => 'a', <--  Now moved to position #1
  'apples' => '23',
  'tomatoes' => '21',
  'nuts' => '22',
  'bar' => 'b',
)
**/
```

Works on numeric arrays also:

```
$colours = ["green", "blue", "red"];

repositionArrayElement($colours, 2, 0);

var_export($colours);

/** Returns
array (
  0 => 'red', <-- Now moved to position #0
  1 => 'green',
  2 => 'blue',
)
*/
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/1QgKX)

Answer (score 8):

The solution from hakre with two array_splice commands doesn't work with named arrays. The key of the moved element will be lost.

Instead you can splice the array two times and merge the parts.

```
function moveElement(&$array, $a, $b) {
    $p1 = array_splice($array, $a, 1);
    $p2 = array_splice($array, 0, $b);
    $array = array_merge($p2,$p1,$array);
}
```

How does it work:

- First: remove/splice the element from the array
- Second: splice the array into two parts at the position you want to insert the element
- Merge the three parts together

Example:

```
$fruits = array(
    'bananas'=>'12', 
    'apples'=>'23',
    'tomatoes'=>'21', 
    'nuts'=>'22',
    'foo'=>'a',
    'bar'=>'b'
);

moveElement($fruits, 1, 3);

// Result
['bananas'=>'12', 'tomatoes'=>'21', 'nuts'=>'22', 'apples'=>'23', 'foo'=>'a', 'bar'=>'b']
```

Comment: Apples was index 1 and Tomato index 3. In your result Tomato is now 1 and Apples is now index 4, and Instead, nuts is index 3. So how exactly is this the solution?

Comment: You have to start counting from 0. apples is on position 1 and it is moved to position 3

Comment: You swap 1, 3 . **Before: (1= Apples , 3 = nuts) and you get **After**: 1 = Tomatoes 3 = Apples . That is not a swap, it simply moves apples to the correct index (3) but instead of nuts being 1, you have tomatoes being 1 now.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays in PHP are not actual array in the C sens but associative arrays.
But the way to move a value from an index to another is quiet straight forward and is the same as in C++:

Copy the value to move to a temporary buffer, translate all the elements to crush the empty spot at the source position and in the same free up a spot on the destination position.
Put the backup value in the destination spot.

```
function moveElement ($a , $i , $j)
{
      $tmp =  $a[$i];
      if ($i > $j)
      {
           for ($k = $i; $k > $j; $k--) {
                $a[$k] = $a[$k-1]; 
           }        
      }
      else
      { 
           for ($k = $i; $k < $j; $k++) {
                $a[$k] = $a[$k+1];
           }
      }
      $a[$j] = $tmp;
      return $a;
}


$a = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
print_r($a);

$a = moveElement($a, 1, 4);
echo ('1 ->  4');
print_r($a);


$a = moveElement($a, 5, 0);
echo ('5 ->  0' );
print_r($a);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
)
1 ->  4Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 5
)
5 ->  0Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 1
)
```

You'll need to add some Exception handling to have a complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126502/move-value-in-php-array-to-the-beginning-of-the-array) thread which describes a similar problem. The following solution is provided:

```
/**
 * Move array element by index.  Only works with zero-based,
 * contiguously-indexed arrays
 *
 * @param array $array
 * @param integer $from Use NULL when you want to move the last element
 * @param integer $to   New index for moved element. Use NULL to push
 * 
 * @throws Exception
 * 
 * @return array Newly re-ordered array
 */
function moveValueByIndex( array $array, $from=null, $to=null )
{
  if ( null === $from )
  {
    $from = count( $array ) - 1;
  }

  if ( !isset( $array[$from] ) )
  {
    throw new Exception( "Offset $from does not exist" );
  }

  if ( array_keys( $array ) != range( 0, count( $array ) - 1 ) )
  {
    throw new Exception( "Invalid array keys" );
  }

  $value = $array[$from];
  unset( $array[$from] );

  if ( null === $to )
  {
    array_push( $array, $value );
  } else {
    $tail = array_splice( $array, $to );
    array_push( $array, $value );
    $array = array_merge( $array, $tail );
  }

  return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A function that preserves keys:

```
function moveElementInArray($array, $toMove, $targetIndex) {
    if (is_int($toMove)) {
        $tmp = array_splice($array, $toMove, 1);
        array_splice($array, $targetIndex, 0, $tmp);
        $output = $array;
    }
    elseif (is_string($toMove)) {
        $indexToMove = array_search($toMove, array_keys($array));
        $itemToMove = $array[$toMove];
        array_splice($array, $indexToMove, 1);
        $i = 0;
        $output = Array();
        foreach($array as $key => $item) {
            if ($i == $targetIndex) {
                $output[$toMove] = $itemToMove;
            }
            $output[$key] = $item;
            $i++;
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

$arr1 = Array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
$arr2 = Array('A' => 'a', 'B' => 'b', 'C' => 'c', 'D' => 'd', 'E' => 'e');

print_r(moveElementInArray($arr1, 3, 1));
print_r(moveElementInArray($arr2, 'D', 1));
```

Ouput:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => d
    [2] => b
    [3] => c
    [4] => e
)
Array
(
    [A] => a
    [D] => d
    [B] => b
    [C] => c
    [E] => e
)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be I'm wrong but shouldn't it be easier just to make a copy of the array and then replace the values?

```
function swap($input, $a, $b){
  $output = $input;
  $output[$a] = $input[$b];
  $output[$b] = $input[$a];
  return $output;
}

$array = ['a', 'c', 'b'];
$array = swap($array, 1, 2);
```

Comment: This way you only swap two elements But the task is to move

Answer (score 0):

Based on [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12624423/11607574). In case if you need to save key indexes of an associative array, which are could be any number or string:

```
function custom_splice(&$ar, $a, $b){
    $out = array_splice($ar, $a, 1);
    array_splice($ar, $b, 0, $out);
}

function moveElement(&$array, $a, $b) {
    $keys = array_keys($array);

    custom_splice($array, $a, $b);
    custom_splice($keys, $a, $b); 

    $array = array_combine($keys,$array);
}
```

```
$s = '{ 
"21": "b", 
"2": "2", 
"3": "3", 
"4": "4", 
"6": "5", 
"7": "6" 
}';
$e = json_decode($s,true);

moveElement($e, 2, 0); 

print_r($e);

Array
(
    [3] => 3
    [21] => b
    [2] => 2
    [4] => 4
    [6] => 5
    [7] => 6
)
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/cntbB)**

`A previous answer` destroys numeric indexes - makes them start from `0`.

Answer (score 0):

For those who don't like `array_splice` due to "array by reference" `&`, here an `array_slice` variant.
Object oriented and unit tested.

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\API\Common\Sorter;

final class ArraySorter
{
    public function moveItem(int $fromIndex, int $toIndex, array $array): array
    {
        $movingItem = $array[$fromIndex];
        $slicingArray = $array;
        unset($slicingArray[$fromIndex]);

        $startingItems = array_slice($slicingArray, 0, $toIndex);
        $endingItems = array_slice($slicingArray, $toIndex);
        $splicedArray = array_merge($startingItems, [$movingItem], $endingItems);
        return $splicedArray;
    }
}
```

Unit tests

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\API\Tests\Unit\Common;

use App\API\Common\Sorter\ArraySorter;
use PHPUnit\Framework\Assert;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

final class ArraySorterTest extends TestCase
{
    private ArraySorter $arraySorter;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->arraySorter = new ArraySorter();
    }

    /** @dataProvider moveItemProvider */
    public function testMoveItem(int $fromIndex, int $toIndex, array $expectedArray): void
    {
        $array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
        $result = $this->arraySorter->moveItem($fromIndex, $toIndex, $array);
        Assert::assertSame($expectedArray, $result);
    }

    public function moveItemProvider(): array
    {
        return [
            'move first forward' => ['fromIndex' => 0, 'toIndex' => 1, 'expectedArray' => ['b', 'a', 'c', 'd']],
            'move middle forward' => ['fromIndex' => 1, 'toIndex' => 2, 'expectedArray' => ['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']],
            'move middle back' => ['fromIndex' => 2, 'toIndex' => 1, 'expectedArray' => ['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']],
            'move last back' => ['fromIndex' => 3, 'toIndex' => 2, 'expectedArray' => ['a', 'b', 'd', 'c']],
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`EDIT: This answer will not resequence the outputted array as per the OP's specs. It will preserve the original keys/indexs.`

So here is an answer that **supports all array types** *which I've found none of the answers do*:

- numeric arrays `['A','B','C']`
- numeric assoc arrays `[0 => 'A', 11 => 'B', 22 => 'C']`
- assoc arrays `['a' => 'A', 'b' => 'B', 'c' => 'C']`

It's a bit longwinded and takes about **twice the time of the accepted answer by [hakre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367456/hakre)** but it works across the board.

The issue for my use case is that the others depend on the *index* as opposed to the position of the element in the array.

```
    // Call it like so:
    $shiftedArray = ShiftItem($array, 4, 1);

    function ShiftItem(array $array, int $initialPosition, int $finalPosition)
    {
        // Validate args...

        if ($initialPosition === $finalPosition)
            return $array;

        $item = self::ItemFromPosition($array, $initialPosition);

        if ($initialPosition < $finalPosition) {

            $p1 = array_slice($array, 0, $initialPosition, true); // Grab the elements
            $p2 = array_slice($array, $initialPosition + 1, $finalPosition - $initialPosition, true);
            $p3 = array_slice($array, $finalPosition, null, true);

            return $p1 + $p2 + $item + $p3;

        } else if ($initialPosition > $finalPosition) {

            $p1 = array_slice($array, 0, $finalPosition, true); // Grab the elements
            $p2 = array_slice($array, $finalPosition, $initialPosition - $finalPosition, true);
            $p3 = array_slice($array, $initialPosition, null, true);

            return $p1 + $item + $p2 + $p3;

        }
    }

    function ItemFromPosition(array $array, int $position): array
    {
        // Validate args...

        $itemKey = $itemValue = null;
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

            if ($count === $position) {
                $itemKey = $key;
                $itemValue = $value;
                break;
            }

            $count++;
        }

        return [$itemKey => $itemValue];
    }
```

Comment: To be fair, you have extended your answer beyond the scope of the asked question.  This asked question clearly states "index" -- not key, not associative key.  Hakre's answer is appropriate.  It seems this answer is probably more appropriate for a different question which has different requirements to respect and maintain associative keys.  I also see that other answers have preserved original keys, so perhaps this page has already spiralled out of the initial scope.

Comment: You are quite right, @mickmackusa, this answer is off the mark. The op clearly asks for something that will "resequence the indexes so that there are no gaps in the sequence." which this answer does not do. Tough love is still love, so I'll take what I can get :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to create an auxiliary variable.

```
moveElement($a, $i,$j)
  {
  $k=$a[$i];
  $a[$i]=$a[$j];
  $a[$j]=$k;
  return $a;
  }
```

Comment: This is more like `swapElements()`, but not move

Comment: No: `c` will go to `3` and not `2` like in the example.