# Reorder an array and move element

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem with a php function.
What I'd like to get is: reorder an array according to whether or not a condition.

my array's format is:

```
Array ( 
    [id] => 3 
    [idCategory] => 1 
    .... => **
    [images] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [path] => http://ssdds.jpg 
            [type] => logo 
            [default] => false 
            [alt] => 
            ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
            [path] => http://saasdsd.jpg 
            [type] => photo 
            [default] => true 
            [alt] => 
        ) 
        [2] => Array ( 
            [path] => http://saddadsasd.jpg 
            [type] => photo 
            [default] => false 
            [alt] => 
        ) 
    )
    **....
```

As you can see in every image there is a tag called "default, This tag can be TRUE or FALSE. Only a photo can have the TRUE attribute.
I'm interested in:

1) Scroll through the array and see if there is a picture with TRUE attribute in the DEFAULT field;

2) if not exist leave the array as found;

3) If there is a picture with TRUE attribute this photo must be placed at the first position in the array;

How can i do that?

Thank You
Steve

Comment: Using [usort](http://php.net/usort) will probably help.

Comment: may be true for some entries?

Comment: Could you reformat you array,  it's hard to get the struture.

Comment: Instead of adding answers as your edits.. Kindly edit your question itself. It will help others to solve your queries/issues..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried something like below using [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)
with reference to this: [Move an array element to a new index in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12624153/move-an-array-element-to-a-new-index-in-php)

```
$arr['images'] = array ( 
        '0' => array ( 
            'path' => 'http://img1.jpg',
            'type' => 'logo',
            'default' => false,
            'alt' => ''
            ),
        '1' => array ( 
            'path' => 'http://img2.jpg',
            'type' => 'photo',
            'default' => true,
            'alt' => ''
        ),
        '2' => array ( 
            'path' => 'http://img3.jpg',
            'type' => 'photo',
            'default' => false,
            'alt' => ''
        ),
        '3' => array ( 
            'path' => 'http://img4.jpg',
            'type' => 'photo',
            'default' => true,
            'alt' => ''
        ));

        foreach($arr['images'] as $key => $img)
        {
            if($img['default'] == true)
            {
                $out = array_splice($arr['images'], $key, 1);
                array_splice($arr['images'], 0, 0, $out);
            }
        }

        echo "<pre>"; print_r($arr); echo "</pre>";
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [images] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [path] => http://img4.jpg
                    [type] => photo
                    [default] => 1
                    [alt] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [path] => http://img2.jpg
                    [type] => photo
                    [default] => 1
                    [alt] => 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [path] => http://img1.jpg
                    [type] => logo
                    [default] => 
                    [alt] => 
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [path] => http://img3.jpg
                    [type] => photo
                    [default] => 
                    [alt] => 
                )

        )

)
```

Hope this will help you to find out the way you want..!

Answer (score 0):

i didn't write any codes 'cause i don't know how can i do that..

At the moment I've only done tests such as verification of the number of images contained in the array , because i'm thinking about doing a for loop:

```
$countimg = count($data['images']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
<?php
// Check if there is a "falses" and "true"; or only "falses"
// ( assuming there's never more than one default = true)
if(count(array_unique(array_column($your_array['images'],'default'))) > 1)
{
    // Copies the default true
    $first_img = array_filter($your_array['images'],function($image){return !$image['default'];});

    // Build final $images array
    $final_images_array = array_merge(
        // Add the first image (default = true)
        $first_img,
        // Add all the other images.
        array_filter($your_array['images'],function($image){return $image['default'];})
    );
}

// Leaves the array unchanged otherwise
```

Comment: i use your code but the array is not reordered ... at first look I think it's because the IF condition does not find the value " default "...to look at default property i use $data['images']['default']...is this the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
usort($array['images'], function($x,$y){ // $array is your Array. 
    if ($x['default']===true) return -1;
    elseif ($x['default']===false) return 1;  
    else return 0; 
});
```

It sorts array['images'] by your way.

Comment: it works only the first time! i try to explain:
the first time i've used it works perfectly! When i change the default image your code doesn't reorder the array...Array remains the same as the first reordering..

Comment: what do you mean change the default image?

Comment: in backend i can change the default images choosing from a X images present in the array...when i want i can change the default image and the past default image get the FALSE attribute in 'default'. But using your function my array doesn't reorder itself ebery time i change the def image..

Answer (score 0):

If I guess correctly, you are using this "default" stuff to just set the default image. Why not add `[default]` key to the main array, where you can store the index of the default image from the `[images]` array. If no default image set, just keep `null` there.

```
$array = array(
    'default_image' => 0,
    'images' => array(
        '0' => array( 
            'path' => 'http://ssdds.jpg' ,
            'type' => 'logo',
            'alt' => '', 
        ), 
        '1' => array( 
            'path' => 'http://saasdsd.jpg', 
            'type' => 'photo', 
            'alt' => '', 
        ), 
        '2' => array( 
            'path' => 'http://saddadsasd.jpg', 
            'type' => 'photo', 
            'alt' => '', 
        ),
    )
);
```

This way you don't need to filter or sort array at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `usort()` to sort php array like this ...

```
<?php 
$dataArray = array( 
                    'id' => 3 ,
                    'idCategory' => 1 ,
                    'images' => array ( 
                            0 => array ( 
                                'path' => 'http://ssdds.jpg' ,
                                'type' => 'logo',
                                'default' => false,
                                ), 
                            1 => array ( 
                                'path' => 'http://saasdsd.jpg' ,
                                'type' => 'photo' ,
                                'default' => true,
                            ) ,
                            2 => array ( 
                                'path' => 'http://saddadsasd.jpg',
                                'type' => 'photo',
                                'default' => false,
                            ),
                        ) 
                 );

foreach($dataArray['images'] as $key => $data)
{
    if(in_array(1,$data))
    {
        usort($dataArray['images'], build_sorter('default'));
        $dataArray['images'] = $dataArray['images'];
    }
}

function build_sorter($key)
{
    return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
        return strnatcmp($b[$key], $a[$key]);
    };
}

var_dump($dataArray);
```

This will Output:

```
array (size=3)
  'id' => int 3
  'idCategory' => int 1
  'images' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'path' => string 'http://saasdsd.jpg' (length=18)
          'type' => string 'photo' (length=5)
          'default' => boolean true
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          'path' => string 'http://saddadsasd.jpg' (length=21)
          'type' => string 'photo' (length=5)
          'default' => boolean false
      2 => 
        array (size=3)
          'path' => string 'http://ssdds.jpg' (length=16)
          'type' => string 'logo' (length=4)
          'default' => boolean false
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://eval.in/572049)**

Answer (score 0):

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return $b['default'];
}

$picture_arr = array("images" => 
  array(
    array("path" => "http://image1.jpg", "type" => "logo", "default" => false),
    array("path" => "http://image2.jpg", "type" => "logo", "default" => false),
    array("path" => "http://image3.jpg", "type" => "logo", "default" => true),
    array("path" => "http://image4.jpg", "type" => "logo", "default" => false),
    array("path" => "http://image5.jpg", "type" => "logo", "default" => true),
  )
);


usort($picture_arr['images'], 'sortByOrder');
```

this will sort your array.