# How to change php array position with condition in Php

Tags: php, arrays

I am working with PHP,I have array and i want to change position of array, i want to display matching value in first position,For example i have following array

```
$cars=('Toyota','Volvo','BMW');
```

And i have variable $car="BMW" And i want to match this variable with array and if match then this array value should be at first in array
so expected result is (matching record at first position)

```
$cars=('BMW','Volvo','Toyota');
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: That's not an array. Arrays are surrounded with square brackets `[]`, not parentheses `()`.

Comment: Create a new empty array. Then loop your $cars array. For each element, check if the value matched your search value. If yes, you use array_unshift to prepend the value to the front of the new array. If not, then you just use array_push to add the value to the end of the new array.

Comment: @Vlam no need of foreach, please look at my answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move an array element to a new index in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12624153/move-an-array-element-to-a-new-index-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and [array_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php) for this purpose. try below mentioned code

```
$cars=array(0 =>'Toyota',1 =>'Volvo',2 =>'BMW');
$car="BMW";

$resultIndex = array_search($car, $cars); //get index 

if($resultIndex)
{
$replacement = array(0 =>$car,array_search($car, $cars)=>$cars[0]); //swap with  0 index 
$cars = array_replace($cars, $replacement); //replace 
}

print_r($cars);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved in one line with `array_merge` and `array_unique` array functions.

```
$cars=['Toyota','Volvo','BMW'];
$car="BMW";

$cars2 = array_unique(array_merge([$car],$cars));
//$cars2: array(3) { [0]=> string(3) "BMW" [1]=> string(6) "Toyota" [2]=> string(5) "Volvo" }
```

$car is always at the beginning of the new array due to `array_merge`. If $car already exists in the $cars array, `array_unique` will remove it. If $car is not present in the $cars array, it is added at the beginning.  If this behavior is not desired, you can use `in_array` to test whether $car is also contained in the $cars array.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest is to "sort" by "Value = BMW", "Value != BMW".

The function that sorts and resets the keys (i.e. starts the resulting array from 0, which you want) is usort (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

So your comparison function will be `If ($a == "BMW") return 1, elseif ($b == "BMW") return -1, else return 0;` (Paraphrased, don't expect that to work exactly - need to leave a bit for you to do!)

Comment: `,` should be `;`

Comment: @Barmar : no, it shouldn't :). It's a comma. I'm not writing the solution, but paraphrasing how the OP can work out what the solution is and then they can work it out themselves next time, and the time after that; otherwise I can send a bill if the OP wants me to write their application.