# PHP - how to move an array element from one array position to another?

Tags: php, arrays

`$x = array ("was", "the", "16th", "president")`

to

`$x = array ( "the", "was", "16th", "president")`

to

`$x = array ( "the",  "16th", "was", "president")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving up/down an item in the array by its value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212312/moving-up-down-an-item-in-the-array-by-its-value)

Comment: Welcome to SO, try to explain your problem and read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Save it temporarily in a variable:

```
$temp = $x[1];
$x[1] = $x[0];
$x[0] = $temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$x = array ("was", "the", "16th", "president");

$count = count($x);
for($i = 0; $i < $count-1; $i++ ) {
    $temp = $x[$i+1];
    $x[$i+1] = $x[$i];
    $x[$i] = $temp;
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. This might be solve your issue.

```
$x = array ("was", "the", "16th", "president");
$temp = array($x[1], $x[2], $x[0], $x[3]);
$x = $temp;
```

Answer (score -1):

PHP has different functions for sorting arrays. For your scenario use usort().

> usort — Sort an array by values using a user-defined comparison function. Explanation and examples: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php